# Multiple relations navigation property is null EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, class, entity-framework-6

I had a many to many relationship, and I must reuse one of the entities in this relationship to create a new one to many relationship.

I did it but something weird happen, i show my class definition to be able to explain the problem

```
public partial class Transformador
{
    [Key]
    public string UniqueCode { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Refrigeracion_x_Trafo> Refrigeracion { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<Datos_Garantizados> Datos_Garantizados { get; set; }
    //more stuff
}

public partial class Modos_Refrigeracion
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Refrigeracion_x_Trafo> Refrigeracion_x_Trafo { get; set; }                
    public virtual ICollection<Datos_Garantizados> DatosGarantizados { get; set; }    
}

public partial class Refrigeracion_x_Trafo
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string UniqueCode { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Id_refrigeracion { get; set; }
}

public partial class Datos_Garantizados
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0 )]        
    public string UniqueCode { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(IdRefrigeracion))]
    public Modos_Refrigeracion TipoDeRefrigeracion { get; set; }
    public int? IdRefrigeracion { get; set; }
}
```

The thing is, when i got a `Transformador` and one `Datos_Garantizados` of the `ICollection` the `Modos_Refrigeracion` object is null.

The strange thing here is that if `IdRefrigeration` (within `Datos_Garantizados`) matches one of the records in the table `Refrigeracion_X_Trafo`, it works correctly!

The relation should be like this:

`1` `Transformador` has Many `Modos_Refrigeracion` and Many `Datos_Garantizados`
Many `Modos_Refrigeracion` has Many `Transformador` and Many `Datos_Garantizados`
1 Datos_Garantizados has `1` `Transformador` and 1 `Modos_Refrigeracion`

How can i solve this?

Thanks!

**Edit** the `IdRefrigeracion` property allways has the correct value, the problem is that the `Modos_Refrigeracion` object is null

Comment: What's the definition of `Accesorio_x_Trafos` and `Refrigeracion_x_Trafo`?

Comment: @schlonzo ty for read, Accesorio_x_Trafos isnt related, was my mistake, about `Refrigeracion_x_Trafo` is the class i'm using to map the many to many relation between `Transformador` and `Modos_Refrigeracion`

Comment: The problem is solved, was because i didnt declare TipoDeRefrigeracion  as virtual